# Best visual way to build a "near isometric" 2D view

Tags: 2d, tilemap, isometric, perspective, map-editor

I'm working hard in a 2D platform game, as far as I got is a standard 2D view (only x and y are visible)

But I want to change the perspective so I can see the floor also.

But the MapBuilder I developed works perfectly based on TILES (so my 2D works very well)

I wanna know the easiest way to add the ground on top of the floor without switching to full 3D with rotationed Rectangles.

The best I tought is to create a "magic" rectangle on top of my ordinary floor to make this fake perspective. But this still lead me to problems on multi-floors.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, for reference?

Answer (score 3):

### These are the two main solutions I can think of:

- **If you use tilesets**, add a rectangle on top of your tiles. You should also move the collision detection up a bit, not to have your character walking on the edge of the blocks. However, this can easily look like the character's feet are passing through the ground but it mostly depends on the quality of the tiles. Here is an example where it looks very good to me.

[image: Example of 2D game]

- **If you use "plain" images** you have to draw the upper part too, where the characters are walking. The collision detection should be a little upper or else it will look weird.

[image: Example of 2D game]

This is just a display change, it can't bring other problems than looking weird or ugly.

Comment: Well a Tileset approach would works perfectly and it is the kind of "fake" perspective I would like to try... i'll mark this as right as soon as i get a sample working